# Failed to deploy Rails app to WebLogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy very simple Rails application to Oracle WebLogic server. It's just a default application created by a command like "**jruby -S rails new myapp**".

It works fine if I run a development server ("**jruby -S rails server**").
But when I deploy it to WebLogic, I receive an exception:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no method 'getInstance' for arguments (org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone) on Java::OrgJodaTimeChrono::GJChronology
```

**My environment:**

OS: Windows 8.1
Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
jRuby: jruby 1.7.10 (1.9.3p392) 2014-01-09 c4ecd6b
WebLogic: 12.1.2 
Rails: 4.0.2
Warbler: 1.4.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is a common issue with WebLogic caused by conflicting JodaTime (jar) library.

it's fixable by adding a `weblogic.xml` descriptor and telling WL to **"prefer"** (Java) classes from *WEB-INF/lib* details at the wiki : https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack/wiki/Deploying-with-WebLogic

Comment: did you check that *weblogic.xml* was put in the .war under WEB-INF ?

Comment: Yes! I checked it both in the generated war and in a WebLogic folder where it was deployed.<br/>
In addition I noticed that there is no joda-time*.jar file neither in the jRuby folder nor in my app folder. Can it be a reason of my trouble?

Comment: joda classes are there part of `jruby-core.jar` this must be a WL configuration issue than - you need to verify that it is truly preferring application classes instead of those in WL's CP, there might be a WL setting somewhere that still disables it or something - you should know better since you have the server at your fingerprints!

Comment: Heh, I rebooted WebLogic and now everything works fine. :)<br/>
Thanks!