# Failed to deploy sinatra web app to weblogic 12

Tags: sinatra, weblogic, jruby, jruby-rack

I have the same situation as in
[Failed to deploy rails app to weblogic ....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154145/failed-to-deploy-rails-app-to-weblogic)

but in example "Hello world" in Sinatra. Weblogic 12. Modified weblogic.xml does not help me :(

```
####<Oct 9, 2014 12:24:39 PM UZT> <Info> <Deployer> <dorlov-Inspiron-3721> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <67bcaffe-f332-43c1-a76e-e511b3ec24ad-00000001> <1412839479333> <BEA-149059> <Module hello.war of application hello is transitioning from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server DefaultServer.> 
####<Oct 9, 2014 12:24:39 PM UZT> <Info> <Deployer> <dorlov-Inspiron-3721> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <67bcaffe-f332-43c1-a76e-e511b3ec24ad-00000001> <1412839479336> <BEA-149060> <Module hello.war of application hello successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server DefaultServer.> 
####<Oct 9, 2014 12:24:39 PM UZT> <Info> <ServletContext-/hello> <dorlov-Inspiron-3721> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <67bcaffe-f332-43c1-a76e-e511b3ec24ad-00000001> <1412839479409> <BEA-000000> <INFO: jruby 1.7.16 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-25 575b395 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51-b13 +jit [linux-amd64]> 
####<Oct 9, 2014 12:24:39 PM UZT> <Info> <ServletContext-/hello> <dorlov-Inspiron-3721> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <67bcaffe-f332-43c1-a76e-e511b3ec24ad-00000001> <1412839479411> <BEA-000000> <INFO: using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime> 
####<Oct 9, 2014 12:24:43 PM UZT> <Info> <ServletContext-/hello> <dorlov-Inspiron-3721> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <67bcaffe-f332-43c1-a76e-e511b3ec24ad-00000001> <1412839483193> <BEA-000000> <An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup
no method 'getInstance' for arguments (org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone) on Java::OrgJodaTimeChrono::GJChronology
--- System
jruby 1.7.16 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-25 575b395 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51-b13 +jit [linux-amd64]
Time: 2014-10-09 12:24:43 +0500
Server: WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0 Wed May 21 18:53:34 PDT 2014 1604337 Oracle WebLogic Server Module Dependencies 12.1 Tue Mar 11 15:35:15 MDT 2014 WebLogic Jersey Server Integration 3.0 Fri Feb 21 10:55:11 UTC 2014 
jruby.home: classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home
```

Comment: that does seem really weird ... the cause is the same thing as the referenced q - WL has it's joda.jar while JRuby packages up it's own version as well and since the web app's CL does delegate by default the server's .jar gets loaded. maybe you need to share more details JRuby-Rack version and how the .war is packaged

Comment: Resolved.    <prefer-application-packages>
       <package-name> org.jruby.*</package-name>
       <package-name> jruby.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

Comment: could we see your full weblogic.xml descriptor so we can update the wiki for future generations ? would be great if you did answer your questions anyways ...

Comment: <weblogic-web-app xmlns=" http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app ">
  <container-descriptor>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
   <prefer-application-packages>
       <package-name> org.jruby.*</package-name>
       <package-name> jruby.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>

Comment: thanks, I posted the answer for you. I'm a bit surprised it worked like that, but I thing I understand why. Still the most important bit seems `<package-name>org.joda.*</package-name>` that alone should be enough ... let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

straight from the updated wiki: https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack/wiki/Deploying-with-WebLogic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- this should work with anything >= WL 10.3, make sure your xmlns is right
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">-->
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.joda.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.jruby.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

this should be the alternative to do it (even for WebLogic versions before 12)